# erlang output the list length after having it run a quicksort - Part 2

Tags: function, io, erlang, quicksort, erl

So my first question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027957/erlang-is-it-possible-to-output-the-list-length-after-having-it-run-a-quicksor) and it makes sense. It was able to output a list length after a sort, but originally I was asking as a way to use io:format function for a sort/0. But my next follow up, is how to use it with the sort/1? I've been able to work it out to give it, but it's giving it while recursion so I'm getting multiple lines and incorrectly. My question is how do I do the io:format once it's done with quick sort (also note, I also want the list to have no repeats) so I get just the one line of the length instead of the multiple lines I'm getting below?

Here's what I have and am getting:

```
-module(list).
-export([sort/1]).

sort([]) -> [];


sort([First|Rest]) -> 

    io:format("~nThe length of the list is ~w~n", [length([First]++Rest)])),


    sort([ X || X <- Rest, X < First]) ++
    [First] ++
    sort([ X || X <- Rest, X > First]).
```

And the output:

```
56> list:sort([2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,8,6]).

The length of the list is 10

The length of the list is 2

The length of the list is 5

The length of the list is 2

The length of the list is 1
[1,2,3,6,8]
```

So the sorted list with no duplicates is correct, but how do I fit the io:format function in there to show like this?

```
56> list:sort([2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,8,6]).

[1,2,3,6,8]
The length of the list is 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, you are not going to be able to discriminate the usage of `io:format/2 inside` the recursive function as it is.

You could separate the printing from the recursive part.

```
sort(L)->
   Result = quicksort(L),
   io:format("~nThe length of the list is ~w~n", [length(Result)]),
   Result.

quicksort([]) -> [];
quicksort([First|Rest]) -> 
   quicksort([ X || X <- Rest, X < First]) ++
   [First] ++
   quicksort([ X || X <- Rest, X > First]).
```

Comment: Ya my problem was I was not thinking of it as a function within the function. So this makes sense. Thanks for answering my rookie question.